# Как сделать так, чтобы поиск в браузере находил букву без учета языка?

Tags: кодировка, браузер

У меня есть веб-страница с номерами заказов формата 1-9999 и A001, A002, ..... ,A999. Где A- буква английской раскладки. Нужно сделать, чтобы через ctrl+F бразуер находил нужный номер заказа как через русскую так и английскую раскладку. Есть ли простое некостыльное решение?

У меня была идея невидимым шрифтом (белым по белому например) поверх номера заказа с англ буквой писать номер с русской буквой, но как-то некрасиво.

Comment: Простое и некостыльное решение - делать изначально правильные номера заказов, чтобы только английские символы использовались.

Comment: Какими русскими буквами вы замените W, V, Q, например, чтобы было некостыльно? Не проще ли перековертировать A001 в 10001 при выводе?

Comment: @Инквизитор В системе и так изначально без костылей на английском. Нашим операторам, работающих с заказами, удобнее искать через русскую раскладку, в связи с чем и появилась задача.

Comment: @NoSkill W, V, Q и другие не имеющие визуального эквивалента буквы, заменять не планировалось. А эти номера, в которые вы предлагаете переконвертировать, уже прошли, и мы сделали в формате через буквы, так как стало много цифр в номерах. В любом случае, уже решил проблему костылем, через невидимый номер заказа с русской буквой.